# File save dialog with cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova app and I want that the user can choose the folder where to save a file (which was created by the app in externalDataDirectory).
Essentially, I want to give the possibility to the user to move that file in a his chosen folder by a file save dialog.
Is there a cordova plugin to open a file save dialog ?

Comment: May be you can use this plugin to infer the file path - https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath and then code to save the file in respective path

Comment: That plugin opens a file save dialog? I want that user decides the path where to save the file.

Comment: yes ,(as @Gandhi said) this plugin will help you to enable the user choose a path.

Comment: Were you able to successfully use this plugin? As far as I can tell it seems to only export a single function that takes in a relative path and returns a full path. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I didn't try that plugin I implented by myself page in which to visualize directory and files

Answer (score 0):

For those coming across this question in the future, there are plugins for both the File/Open and File/Save functionality on iOS and Android:

- [cordova-plugin-chooser](https://github.com/cyph/cordova-plugin-chooser) displays the native Open dialog, allowing the user to select a file, and then returns that file's `uri`. You then use `cordova-plugin-file`'s `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` call to get the file and parse it from there.
- [cordova-plugin-save-dialog](https://github.com/Amphiluke/cordova-plugin-save-dialog) takes a Blob, opens the native Save dialog, and allows the user to save either locally or to the cloud.

These two plugins can help your app "legally" get around the sandboxing and open/save files that it wouldn't otherwise have access to.